# binding HandlerInterceptor to HttpInvokerServiceExporter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In the spring, is there a way to bind `HandlerInterceptor` to `HttpInvokerServiceExporter` via `XML` configuration?

I've seen the discussion on this topic elsewhere ( http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.springframework.user/4730 ), where it sounds like not a problem. 
However as I could not achieve it, could someone provide a sample?

Let's assume this is my current spring configuration XML sample: (how should I bind these 2?)

```
<bean id="MyHandlerInterceptor"
    class="sample.MyHandlerInterceptor">
</bean>

<bean name="/MyExposedPOJO"
    class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="MyExposedPOJO" />
    <property name="serviceInterface"
        value="sample.MyExposedInterface" />
</bean>
```

Thanks.